# iOS - Calling SceneDelegate method from ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I tried following code to call Scene Delegate func from a VC and getting error

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

```
 let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! SceneDelegate
 sceneDelegate.initializeFirstViewController()
```

Is there any way i can call `SceneDelegate` func from VC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIApplication.shared.delegate` is `AppDelegate` not `SceneDelegate` You need

```
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate {    
   // to do 
}
```

Comment: thanks..... for answering